# Registry points to wrong python path(C:\Python27\ArcGIS) instead of (C:\Python27) when installing a Py Package(Scipy)

Tags: python, scipy, registry, arcgis

I'm trying to install scipy and pip install is not working for me. I downloaded the scipy installer from the web, but when I run it, it tries to install to C:\Python27\ArcGIS\ instead of just C:\Python27 , because (it says) the registry points to such path (I have ArcGIS installed but I don't use it anymore and I don't want to use that path for development of other python applicatons). The installer of scipy won't let me change the python installation path.

The path environment variable is set to c:\python27, there is no arcgis in the path. 
I have successfully installed other packages to the correct python location using pip install just from the cmd since the correct python location is in the env var path, but for scipy pip wouldn't work..

I went to the registry, and searched for the previous path, and changed it to the correct one in most of the cases I could find (there are tons... )
I tried reinstalling python, but everytime I run the scipy installer it keeps saying the registry points to C:\Python27\ArcGIS\

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing the free Anaconda python distribution.  It's totally self-contained and doesn't require or need you to modify registry values.  Other benefits include being able to easily install packages that the Continuum and others in the community have built at anaconda.org.  You can get Anaconda at
https://www.continuum.io/ and after installing, you will already have scipy, as well as many other useful packages.